# Crystal Report Product key is missing Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, vb6, license-key

I have installed Visual Basic 6 and Crystal Report 8.5 at Windows 8.1.

Then I get the error in VB6 IDE for Crystal report like:

> Product key is missing or expired.

I have followed the step and crystal report is working fine alone but under VB6 IDE it still shows message for entering product key.

[image]

[Reference](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1223910)

1. On the 'Start' menu, click 'Run'.
2. Type 'Regedit' in the 'Open' text box, and then click 'OK'.
3. In the Windows Registry Editor, navigate to the following sub key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SEAGATE SOFTWARE\CRYSTAL REPORTS\KEYCODES\CR DEV

4. Right-click the 'CR DEV' sub key and then click 'New' > 'Binary Value'. Name this new Binary Value 'Serial'. Do not enter a value for it.
5. Close the Windows Registry Editor.
6. Open CR and on the 'Help' menu click 'Register / Change Address'.
7. Follow the Registration Wizard to register CR.

CR will now register without an error message appearing.

Comment: Any difference when you run VB6 as Administrator?

Comment: same message for entering product key